# strange CPYF issue when copy from a query output

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have a field in query from database table defined : it is a total of group QTY shipped form a previous Query. The Definition in the query is

```
(   IDSHP#01   ZONED       16  2      16       )
```

and in the PF

```
60  T01.IDSHP#01      IDSHP# TOTAL                                   16    2
```

I then try to Copy this to a PF (*MAP *DROP) all the other fields are copying fine but this `IDSHP#01` is getting all .00 where there is data in the file that is copied. What could this be?

I am ready to abandon this method but wanted to show data to the manager as this was working a few weeks ago.

```
 R MDL500R                   TEXT

   IDDOCD         8 00           
   IDINV#         8              
   IDORDT         3              
   IDPRT#        15              
   OHVIAC         3              
   IDSHP#01      16 02           
 K IDINV#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Look at the job log.  Are there any messages at all?

2) Do a DSPFFD on both files.  Make sure the name and size is the same in each.  It's possible that the source does not match the object for one or both files.